# Why can't I mark an event as NotNull?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper

```
public class EventBus<T>
{
    [NotNull] // annotation not valid on this declaration type
    private static event Action<T> Events;

    static EventBus()
    {
        // we always have a do-nothing event handler so we don't have to worry about null checks and race conditions
        Events += T => { };
    }
```

As seen in the comment, I explicitly don't want to have to deal with null checking the Events everywhere.  This is solved by assigning a default do-nothing event at construction that is never called.  It is not surprising that Resharper can't automatically figure this out so I wanted to annotate it with the NotNull annotation.  Unfortunately, it would appear that NotNull cannot be applied to events, yet Resharper doesn't hesitate to warn me about a "Possible 'System.NullReferenceException'" anytime I call my events.

If resharper is going to notice the error, it should be possible to get avoid it with annotations.

Comment: Why bother checking for null if you're going to assign it to a less than intelligible default anyway? If this is a must have then why not just assign your event handler to an empty delegate instance inline? `private static event Action<T> Events = _ => {};`

Comment: You are correct, I should have initialized it inline instead of in the constructor as that would be more clear.  The reason for the default is so that I *don't* have to check for null.  The goal is that when there are no event handlers hooked up, the event can still be "called" `Events()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do it, you can change the attribute (adding a flag `AttributeTargets.Event`) to add support for the event in version 8 it's works.

```
namespace JetBrains.Annotations
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates that the value of the marked element could never be <c>null</c>
    /// </summary>
    /// <example><code>
    /// [NotNull] public object Foo() {
    ///   return null; // Warning: Possible 'null' assignment
    /// }
    /// </code></example>
    [AttributeUsage(
      AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Parameter |
      AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Delegate |
      AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Event, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public sealed class NotNullAttribute : Attribute { }
```

I think they did it because they believe that for events it's better to check it for null before raise. If you try to generate event invocator using Resharper, it will generate something like this:

```
protected virtual void OnMyEvent()
{
    var handler = MyEvent;
    if (handler != null) 
        handler();
}
```

Or you can implement your event explicity:

```
[NotNull]
private static Action<T> _eventsInternal = obj => { };

private static event Action<T> Events
{
    add { _eventsInternal += value; }
    remove { _eventsInternal -= value; }
}

protected static void OnEvents(T arg)
{
    _eventsInternal(arg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on adding my own NotNullAttribute.  Personally, I think it is better to mark the field as NotNull and initialize it than check for null every place you call the event.  Less likely that someone forgets to do the check when adding a call.  Also, it is very easy to miss the subtle race condition when checking an event for null and then calling it, which is another opportunity for bugs.